# Jinja2 : proper way to write [not so] complex template

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm trying to implement a simple calendar webpage.

I'm quite new to Jinja2 but my understanding of templates is that writing HTML code in the Python sources should be avoided as templates are designed for this purpose.

The problem that I'm facing I that I don't see how to write clear templates for this project. I guess there is an overall architecture problem in my project...

My page template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}The title{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Hey</h1>
    <p> I'm happy </p>
    <div id="calendar">
        <table>
            <tr>
                {% for month in range(1, 13) %}
                    <td valign="top" align="center">{# html code for a single month goes here... #}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Each month template is

```
<table>
    <th>{{ month_name }}</th>
    {% for day_number in days %}
        <tr><td>{{ day_number }}</td><td>{{ weekday }}</td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Finally, I have a Python class for a calendar that basically provides helper functions to calculate the days of the month:

```
class Calendar:
    def __init__(self, year):
        self.year = year

    def monthrange(self, month):
        nextmonth = month % 12 + 1
        nextyear = self.year + 1 if nextmonth == 1 else self.year
        firstday = datetime.date(self.year, month, 1)
        lastday = datetime.date(nextyear, nextmonth, 1)
        return (1, (lastday - firstday).days)

    def itermonthdates(self, month):
        first, last = self.monthrange(month)
        for i in range(first, last + 1):
            yield datetime.date(self.year, month, i)

    def tohtml(self):
        def month_to_html(month):
            # !!! This code generate HTML but it should not !!!
            s = '<table>\n'
            s += '<th>{}</th>'.format(MONTHS[month - 1])
            for day in self.itermonthdates(month):
                weekday = WEEKDAYS[day.weekday()]
                d = {'day': day.day, 'weekday': weekday}
                s += '<tr><td>%(day)02d</td><td>%(weekday)s</td></tr>\n' % d
            s += '</table>\n'
            return s

        template_loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath='templates')
        template_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=template_loader)
        template = template_env.get_template('template.html')
        print(template.render(months=[month_to_html(i) for i in range(1, 13)]))
```

So this code only partially work as I don't know how to use Jinja2 to render each month.

Any help would be appreciated.
Ben

Comment: it's pretty unclear what u r asking. `each month` is in a separate page ? if so, use `{% include 'path/to/file.html' %}` this should do the trick. if not, please clarify further.

Comment: I still don't understand what u exactly need, try to be more specific ? if you don't know how to make the page show up. you can use `return render_template('path/to/page.html')` in `Flask`. otherwise I don't know exactly what r u asking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ultimately, months will appear as columns on the same page. My question is: basically, the loop to render the HTML should be in the template, to avoid writing HTML in the Python script. However, here I'm using methods from my custom Calendar class to iterate. So what's the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally *think* I got what you want. **Don't** write `HTML` in `Python`. Instead, you can create the `logic` to your calendar in `Python` then send that data to the template to be populated with `Jinja`. enough talk, let's code a very simple example.

## Simple Example

here we will get the current date to be displayed in a webpage.

`logic.py`

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    import time
    current_time = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    return render_template('template.html', data = current_time)
```

`template.html`

```
{% if data %} # This checks if the variable "data" is set.
     <p> {{data}} </p> ## This will output the date here
```

By applying that to your code, you can send assign any logical data ( which means it requires `Python` to be generated ) to variables and send them to `Jinja` template via adding a second `argument` to `render_template`. Hope I Understood what you wanted right this time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.
I ended with a solution. Don't know if there is a better way. In the end, I pass my `calendar` object to the template.

The page template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}The title{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Hey</h1>
    <p> I'm happy </p>
    <div id="calendar">
        <table>
            <tr>
                {% for month in range(1, 13) %}
                <td valign="top" align="center">
                    {% include 'month_template.html' %}
                </td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The month template:

```
<table>
    <th>{{ calendar.month_name(month) }}</th>
    {% for day_number, weekday in calendar.itermonthdays(month) %}
        <tr><td>{{ day_number }}</td><td>{{ weekday }}</td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

The Python script:

```
class Calendar:
    def __init__(self, year):
        self.year = year

    @staticmethod
    def month_name(monthid):
        return MONTHS[monthid - 1]

    def monthrange(self, month):
        nextmonth = month % 12 + 1
        nextyear = self.year + 1 if nextmonth == 1 else self.year
        firstday = datetime.date(self.year, month, 1)
        lastday = datetime.date(nextyear, nextmonth, 1)
        return (1, (lastday - firstday).days)

    def itermonthdates(self, month):
        first, last = self.monthrange(month)
        for i in range(first, last + 1):
            yield datetime.date(self.year, month, i)

    def itermonthdays(self, month):
        for date in self.itermonthdates(month):
            day = '{:02d}'.format(date.day)
            weekday = WEEKDAYS[date.weekday()]
            yield day, weekday

    def tohtml(self):
        template_loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath='templates')
        template_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=template_loader)
        template = template_env.get_template('template.html')
        print(template.render(calendar=self))
```

Let me know if you see a better approach.

Thanks.

Ben

Comment: u don't need any `to html` functions. any `HTML` scripts should be in the `.html` files.  why are u using `jinja2.FileSystemLoader` and `jinja2.Environment` ? u can just create the class in a separate file, include the class into views, create an object of the class, and just pass the object with `render_template` like in my example. then use the object in `jinja` to display certain attributes of it. that's how I would do it

Comment: Well I'm new at web developing. Isn't what you suggest simply the difference between using the low-level Jinja2 vs the Flask framework?

Comment: To be honest, I never used `jinja.FileSystemLoader` or any similar functions. I have a website that is running on Flask " http://m41kdev3lops.pythonanywhere.com/" which is fully functioning yet never used something like that. Apologies, can't help ya there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You are welcome. sorry for the wrong link I posted. just remove the `/"` at the end and it shall work. Happy Coding !